# Swift: Pan UIImage using constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, autolayout, constraints

I have an `UIImage` in my `viewController` that I am using the `UIPanGesture` on. I am currently using the following code to move it around based on the RayWenderlich tutorial.

```
@IBAction func panImage(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

if let view = sender.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
            y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        exitButton1.center = CGPoint(x:exitButton1.center.x + translation.x, y:exitButton1.center.y + translation.y)
    } 
sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

I am using `auto layout` for this app and have been informed that moving the `UIImage` with `autoLayoutConstraints` should be done instead. I changed to the following code to move the `image`, however, the image is now jumping all over the screen.

```
let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
image1ConstraintX.constant = image1ConstraintX.constant + translation.x
image1ConstraintY.constant = image1ConstraintY.constant + translation.y
```

Is there a better way of moving the `image` using the `constraints`? Can the first method be used and then the `constraints` updated afterwards based on the final position? And how would the second method of moving the `image` look if done correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if a view has active auto layout constraints you should not set its `frame` directly. This is because your change will get overwritten the next time the layout engine makes a pass over the relevant views, and you cannot control when that will happen.

Your solution to update the `constant` of the relevant constraints is the correct one. If you find yourself doing this a lot, you may want to write a method that takes a `CGPoint` and a view, and updates the relevant constraints.

> Can the first method be used and then the constraints updated afterwards based on the final position?

Yes, but you probably don't want to. To accomplish this, you would remove or disable the constraints, modify `frame` as the user pans, and once the user is done panning, set the `constant` on each constraint, and re-enable the layout constraints. This would be more complex than is necessary.